# Using tinyscrollbar meteor package

Tags: javascript, meteor, tinyscrollbar

With the following code:

```js
Template.home.rendered = function() {
    $("#newsfeed").tinyscrollbar();
};
```

calling the plugin from [this meteor packaging of tinyscrollbar](https://github.com/bojan88/meteor-tiny-scrollbar)

I get the following exception:

```
Exception from Deps afterFlush function
function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined
    at Scrollbar.update
```

(a full trace is at [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/EvzrkjnR))

I will be happy to provide more information as needed!

Comment: same issue, would like to know the resolution if you find it. Worked in 0.7.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Did you add all the required html to your page?

Comment: I'm using Meteor, and I added everything as a package. This should have taken care of including everything.

Comment: http://baijs.com/tinyscrollbar/ Look at the examples they need extra html to work.